# Running vmstat slows performance of the unix server?

Tags: unix

Does vmstat degrades performance of the unix server?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, it takes *some* resources to run `vmstat`. However, the amount of resources it needs is tiny, so the performance impact will be negligible (probably not even measurable).

If we take Linux as an example, all `vmstat` does is read a couple of small pseudo-files in `/proc`, format their contents and print out the result.